# Difference between (apply #'somefunc args) and (somefunc args)

Tags: common-lisp, on-lisp

While reading Paul Graham's [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisptext.html) I found the following `function` in **Chapter 4, Utility Functions**.

```
(defun symb (&rest args)
  (values (intern (apply #'mkstr args)))) ;; mkstr function is "applied"
;; which evaluates like in the following example:
> (symb nil T :a)
NILTA
```

I would like to understand what is the difference with the following function, slightly different:

```
(defun symb1 (&rest args)
  (values (intern (mkstr args)))) ;; directly calling mkstr
;; which evaluates like in the following example:
> (symb1 nil T :a)
|(NIL T A)|
```

In this second version, `mkstr` is directly evaluated with `args` arguments, but I don't understand why we need to do `(apply #'mkstr ...)` in the original.

Comment: The rest parameter `ARGS` will contain a list of the given arguments (`(NIL T :A)` in the example). `APPLY` will "splice" that list, so `(apply #'mkstr args)` is the same as `(mkstr nil t :a)`. Without `APPLY` you would be passing the list as a single argument to `MKSTR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `(f args)`, you call `f` with one argument.

With `(apply #'f args)`, you call `f` with as many arguments as the `args` list contains. So if `args` is `(1 2)`, then `(apply #'f args)` is equivalent to `(f 1 2)`.

See [`APPLY`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm).

Comment: And `(f args)` would be equivalent to `(f '(1 2))`

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of APPLY is to call functions with computed argument lists.

Imagine the user enters some arguments and we want to call the function `WRITE`. `WRITE` takes a lot of possible arguments. The first argument is the object to print the rest are keyword value options:

possible keyword arguments for `WRITE`:

```
array base case circle escape gensym
length level lines miser-width pprint-dispatch
pretty radix readably right-margin stream
```

Let's read the argument list as a list using `READ` and call `WRITE` via `APPLY` with the argument list:

```
CL-USER 30 > (loop for input = (read)
                   while input
                   do
                   (format t "~%# ")
                   (apply #'write input)
                   (format t "~%~%"))
((1 5 10 30 55 26 12 17))
# (1 5 10 30 55 26 12 17)

((1 5 10 30 55 26 12 17) :base 16)
# (1 5 A 1E 37 1A C 11)

((1 5 10 30 55 26 12 17) :base 12)
# (1 5 A 26 47 22 10 15)

((1 5 10 30 55 26 12 17) :length 5)
# (1 5 10 30 55 ...)

((1 5 10 30 55 26 12 17) :base 16 :length 5)
# (1 5 A 1E 37 ...)
```

Another way to achieve something similar would have been using EVAL.

```
CL-USER 35 > (let ((f #'+)
                   (args '(20 22)))
               (eql (eval (list* 'funcall f args))
                    (apply f args)))
T
```

Answer (score 2):

Let’s look at the definition of `mkstr`:

```
CL-USER> (defun mkstr (&rest args)
           (with-output-to-string (s)
             (dolist (a args) (princ a s))))
MKSTR
```

it is a function that takes a variable number of arguments, of any type, packs them in a list, and assigns this list to the formal parameter `args` (due to the `&rest` specification of the parameter). Then, the function prints all the elements of this list with `printc`, producing a string that is the result of *concatenating* all the printed representations of them (without intervening spaces). So, for instance:

```
CL-USER> (mkstr '(a b c))
"(A B C)"
CL-USER> (mkstr 3 'A '(A b 4))
"3A(A B 4)"
```

Similarly, the functions `symb` and `symb1` take a variable numbers of arguments and `args` will contain the list formed by them. So, `symb1` calls `mkstr` with a *single* argument, the list of the arguments passed to `symb1`, so that `mkstr` creates a unique string from the list, and finally the list is interned to transform it in an atom. In `symb`, instead, the function `mkstr` is applied to all the arguments *extracted* from the list, since `apply` is used (see the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm#apply)), so that all the elements of the list are concatened together and then transformed into an atom..